# First order non-linear inhomogeneous ODE: $\dot{x}(t) = a(x) + b(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am often encountering equations like
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = a(x) + b(t),$$
where $x(t)$ is a variable of interest, $a(x)$ is some non-linear function, like
$$ a_1(x) = -\mu x/|x|, $$
or
$$ a_2(x) = - a x |x|,$$
and $b(t)$ is some unspecified driving term which depends on the independent variable only.

As far as I'm aware there are essentially no techniques available to solve these equations in general. Is this correct?

In the linear case of $a(x) = - k x$, one uses integrating factors:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} x(t) e^{k t} = e^{k t}b(t) $$
which provides an easily integrated first order equation.

The obvious analogue
$$ \frac{d}{dt} x(t) \exp\Big[-\int^t a(x(t')) dt' \Big] = \exp\Big[-\int^t a(x(t')) dt' \Big]b(t) $$
for the nonlinear case is only an implicit equation in $x(t)$, so it does not help.

Are there other techniques to approach such problems that I should be aware of?

Comment: You're right that there is no general method of solution, indeed, there are examples where there is no solution in terms of the usual functions. There are always numerical methods.

Comment: An implicit equation in $x$ is still a solution to the differential equation.

Comment: Technically the differential equation in $x$ is an implicit solution. Not sure what your point is